# Ruby on Rails client app and api app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a Ruby on Rails application that serves as an API to other web apps. This API has a controller named AcademicTitlesController, in this controller i have a method active_academic_titles.

```
class AcademicTitlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ....
  end
  def active_academic_titles
      @active_academic_titles = AcademicTitle.where(:academic_unit_id => params[:academic_unit_id]).order('name')
  end
end
```

this method renders a rabl view.

On my routes file i have this
    get 'active_academic_titles' => 'academic_titles#active_academic_titles'

Now on the client web application i want to display the json format text(rabl) with html and erb.
On the client web app i have i model

```
class Api < ActiveResource::Base
  MODE = 'dev' # api or dev

  self.site = 'http://localhost:3003/'
  self.format = :json
end
```

This model makes the connection to the API, and each model in the client app inheris from this Api model.

My question is this, what do i need or add to my client app so that i can get the data from the api view?

Answer (score 0):

I am not what your goal is, but to my understanding the controller will render the view unless otherwise specified. So if you want it to act as an API just return in JSON form from the server for example add `render :json => somedata`

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in Api class as

```
class Api < ActiveResource::Base
  MODE = 'dev' # api or dev

  self.site = 'http://localhost:3003/'
  self.element_name = "" # You can also use self.collection_name = "" instead
  self.format = :json
end
```

And to access json from get 'active_academic_titles' => 'academic_titles#active_academic_titles'

You need to write

```
Api.get('active_academic_titles')
```

Note: Make sure that server port is 3003 and server sends json if at endpoint http://localhost:3003/active_academic_titles.json

Extra Info:
This would not be the  most effective way to use of ActiveResource. Generally we should use class name of class inheriting from ActiveResource i.e 'Api' in your case, to be same as endpoint i.e AcademicTitle and also should avoid using `self.element_name = ""` and instead create a endpoint as http://localhost:3003/academic_titles/active_academic_titles.json

Reference link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.6/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html